# AJAX call is broken, NodeJS, Express, Handlebars

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, handlebars.js

I've been working on this for a couple of days. I'm certain its something really stupid, but I'm at the end of my sanity.

The public files are set up properly.

Error Message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: togDefine is not defined
```

Front End HTML:

```
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4"><strong>Heating:</strong> {{#if heating}} {{this.heating}} {{else}} N/A {{/if}}</div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><strong>Cooling:</strong> {{#if cooling}} {{this.cooling}} {{else}} N/A {{/if}}</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <input type="checkbox" id="pvt{{this.id}}" checked="{{this.private}}" onchange="togDefine({{this.id}}, {{this.private}});" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Private" data-off="Public" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" />
     </div>
   </div>
```

AJAX Call:

```
$(function() {

//  Private-Public toggle
let togDefine = (id, pvt) => {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/pvtToggle",
    data: {
      id: id,
      newState: (pvt === 'true') ? false : true
    },
    success: function(text) {
      if (text === 'ok') {
        pvtSuccess(id, pvt);
      } else {
        console.log('updatePvt failed');
      }
    }
  });

};


let pvtSuccess = (id, pvt) => {
  $('#pvt' + id).attr('checked', (pvt === 'true') ? 'false' : 'true');
};


});
```

Back End:

```
//TOGGLE Private vs Public PROPERTY
app.put('/api/pvtToggle/', isAuthenticated, function(request, response) {
  db.Prop.update({
    private: request.params.newState
  }, {
    where: {
      id: request.params.id
    }
  }).then(data => {
    response.send('ok');
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

});
```

Please help me figure out why the request isn't working properly. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `togDefine()` is defined inside this block:

```
$(function() { /* in here */ })
```

Therefore, that function name is only available inside that block and is not available to your HTML.  Since just defining a function doesn't actually execute anything, there is really no reason to define a function inside of that kind of block unless you ONLY want the symbol available inside that block.

Since you explicitly don't want that here, just move the definition of `togDefine()` outside that block.

Comment: Ok, so that fixed the first issue. Now I'm getting this error:
POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/pvtToggle/ 404 (Not Found)

If you have any thoughts on that I would really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Eric - The server code you should is for a PUT, not a POST.  That code also needs to send a response back to the client in the `.catch()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a legend!